# Loading first occurance of item in array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml, duplicate-data

I'm using SimpleXML to parse a rss feed and if an attribute in returned arrays by SimpleXML matches with my string show data. but some items are duplicated in XML file and I want to use just their first occurrence. but I'm getting all the duplicated results.

```
foreach($feed->city as $city){
    if(in_array($city['Name'], $cities)){
        echo $city['Name'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

where $feed->city is my XML data and $cities is my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use php's Xpath library to do this.   Xpath 2.0 could do this directly, but the built in Xpath 1.0 language still gets you very close.

```
    <!-- language: lang-php -->
$xmlDocument = new DOMDocument();
    if ($xmlDocument->load('file.xml')) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDocument);
    $nodeList = $xpath->query('//city/@Name', $xmlDocument);
```

from here you have a DOMNodeList class.  throw it in an array and remove duplicates.  I don't ahve a php environment around right now to finish it up, but I wanted to offer a different direction than just simplXML by itself.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I want.
I have an xml file like this
 <city Name="city1" Min="3" Max="12" Status="7015" Category="5" />
 <city Name="city2" Min="-2" Max="10" Status="7009" Category="5" />
 <city Name="city3" Min="1" Max="4" Status="7015" Category="5" />
 <city Name="city2" Min="-2" Max="10" Status="7009" Category="23" />
I have extracted this tags to an array with SimpleXML but as you can see city2 is duplicated but in 2 diffrent categories.
I want to remove one of them in my array.

Comment: by remove, I mean remove the whole city2 tag. and array_unique didn't worked.